# ImageView inside LinearLayout does not show when "android:layout_weight" on LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my Code

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/preference_question_optionTwo" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
         <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now here when i apply **android:layout_weight="1"** on LinearLayout the image does not appear.Without this property image is displayed.

What i want is to divide the layout into two parts. Both parts containing the same code above i.e a radio button and besides that an image and a text

**Update This is how i want it**

[image]

This is what i am getting as output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout weight property is for elements within a linear layout. You should give each half of the screen the same weight and put them both within a linear layout.

Here's what you need:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

<!-- first half -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/preference_question_optionTwo" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
         <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

<!-- first half, same weight as first half -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton android:id="@id/preference_question_optionTwo" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
         <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer was able to do what i wanted but the **android:layout_width="wrap_content"** property was not giving me output properly ,it didn't cover the whole screen.So i changed the property **android:layout_width="match_parent"** the image disappeared.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention the property i changed is for the topmost parent LinearLayout

Comment: How about changing the width of all of them to `match_parent`? That should do what you want.

Comment: Also, for better performance, make each internal layout's height 0dp.

Comment: i am such an idiot.While i was changing the width to match_parent, i noticed i had set the width to fill_parent for my RadioButton and that was causing the radioButton to take up the whole layout and pushing the imageView out of the layout.Thnx your tip showed me the mistake i was doing.Since your answer was close to what i was trying to achieve and your tip gave away the mistake i did originally i am accepting your answer.

Comment: Great. I'll adjust my answer to reflect all that's needed for this scenario.

Comment: Actually you need to change the Top most `LinearLayout's android:layout_width="wrap_content"` property to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score 3):

You didn't share the rest of your code or your intentions on how you want to divide the screen into two: vertically or horizontally.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/preference_question_optionOne" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
           <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/preference_question_optionTwo" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
           <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It seems that you got confused by the weight concept. It will be more clear this way, I guess. You should divide the parent's width or height according to those weights. Also don't forget to use it with `0dp`.

If you want to divide the parent vertically, use this combination:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent" <!--or wrap_content-->
android:layout_weight="x"
```

and for horizontally

```
android:layout_height="match_parent" <!--or wrap_content-->
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="x"
```

Comment: This only divides the screen into two halves, one half is just a radio button and the other half is just the image and text. Which is not what he wanted.

Comment: `Both parts containing the same code above i.e a radio button and besides that an image and a text` From this sentence, I understood exactly that.

Comment: Oh ok... Two same `LinearLayout`s. I'm going to update the answer

Comment: Actually i wanted to divide the screen horizontally.Not vertically.

Comment: You want to have two linearlayouts to have same width, right? See the updated code. Don't forget to delete the comments I put inside xml.

Comment: This was the last update. I suggest you to work this code and find your own way.

Comment: Ya the code works,But didn't solve my problem.Your code places the imageview under the radio button.Which i was getting previously.But as u can see my update i need the radio button to be in horizontal with the ImageView not in vertical.When i make the radio button and ImageView in  horizontal the image disappears.That is what i want to achieve.I have used DDMS to check the output and the image vieww is not included in the layout itself.Check my update

Comment: Ok, this is how you need to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: Actually Eran Goldin's answer below satisfies what i want to achieve but not fully .i have added a comment to it ,if u can please check it.

Comment: What is the problem with this code? You need to specify the problem.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code your code was placing the `imageview` below my `radioButton` instead of placing it horizontally with the `radiobutton`. Anyways i figured out the mistake i was doing which was causing my `imageview` move out of the layout.
My mistake :i had put fill_parent for my `radiobutton` which caused the `radiobutton` to take up the whole Layout pushing the `imageview` out when placed horizontally.
Althout the answer did not gave me the exact answer i am still voting it up as i learned more about the `weight` property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59500/discussion-between-0x5f3759df-and-deb).

Answer (score 0):

If You need to divide Your layout in two parts with the same width, you need to set childs width to `fill_parent` and set the same wieght (> 1) to children.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/preference_question_optionTwo" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```